# phpmailer prints long list of details (CLIENT -> SERVER) when sending email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, mailer

I have got a script working with PHPMailer.

When i run it to send an email, the PHPMailer send the email successfully.

**But ALSO echo long list of email sending information (CLIENT -> SERVER) like:**

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-server.mywebsitese.com ESMTP Exim 4.84 #2 Tue, 27 Jan 2015 08:37:57 +0200 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.mywebsite.com
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-server.mywebsite.com Hello server.mywebsite.com [xx.xxx.xx.xx]250-SIZE 52428800250-8B9uLITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5h9uLbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: bm9yZXBseUBsZWJh9uLbm9uLWxvdHRvLmNvbQ==
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc39uLdvcmQ6
.
.
.
.Very
.
.
.Long
.
.
.List of SERVER -> CLIENT / CLIENT SERVER
.
Message sent!
```

The script activated by:

```
            if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
            echo "Message sent!";
```

What I really want is to only send the email, print MESSAGE SENT, no need of this long list..

Is this easily done?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried turning off debugging? Try something like `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`

Comment: Cyclone THANK YOU SOOOOOOOO MUCH, worked :), How can I start your answer? I am new here..

Comment: After you have created a `PHPMailer` instance: `$mail = new PHPMailer(); $mail->SMTPDebug = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be debug information. Try to disable debugging by setting `SMTPDebug` to `0` right after you have created an instance of `PHPMailer`:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `SMTPDebug` is an integer value; setting it to 0 disables debug output. It's off by default, so you should not need to do anything to disable it.

Comment: @Synchro - i edited My answer. I know its off by default but i suspected that the OP turned it on somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`, it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer has 4 levels for debugging. Debugging closes with 0.

- **SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0):** Disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default).
- **SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT (1):** Output messages sent by the client.
- **SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER (2):** as 1, plus responses received from the server (this is the most useful setting).
- **SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION (3):** as 2, plus more information about the initial connection - this level can help diagnose STARTTLS failures.
- **SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL (4):** as 3, plus even lower-level information, very verbose, don't use for debugging SMTP, only low-level problems.

For more detailed information, you can view [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/SMTP-Debugging)'s official github account.

Answer (score 0):

$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
This is working for my script.

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly the same answer given by @Deepti-Gehlot in 2015 ;)